# Problems regarding Android Image Sizes in S3 and S2 ?

Tags: android, xml, image, resolution

Can someone please help me i have two images having size of 512*512   and another one with 114*114    can someone let me know where should i need to put these images either in hdpi folder or in mdpi  folder please mention sizes and their correct folder names as well ?

Answer (score 2):

We cannot tell you which folder to put it in because you have not told us what size you want the images to be on the screen in dp units.

I recommend reading the [Supporting Different Densities](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html) documentation.

The first step is to decide how large you want the image to be in density-independt pixels (dps). Let's say you want your 512 x 512px image to be 512 x 512dps.

Assets in the mdpi folder are not scaled (1dp at mdpi = 1 px). You would thus place your 512px image in the mdpi folder. If you want to better support other resolutions, you might create a 1024px version of the asset for the xhdpi folder.

Answer (score 2):

If you want these image to load in their default resolution, =unscaled(512^2 & 144^2) then you may place them to `/res/drawable-nodpi/` folder(create if needed)

Also, check out [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can refer [here.](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Believe me it will help you, spend an hour reading this and save a day, i had spent days searching for this while my program was done!
Moreover if you have problem not only re-sizing but how the layout looks, you can create multiple layouts like layout-small,layout-large,layout-xlarge, for the different screen sizes.
Text from the page i sent you:

For example, if you have a bitmap drawable that's 48x48 pixels for medium-density screen (the size for a launcher icon), all the different sizes should be:

36x36 for low-density

48x48 for medium-density

72x72 for high-density

96x96 for extra high-density

Another very usefull link is
[Iconography!](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html)